# Start vim with ex-command and append it to vim's command history

Tags: invocation

When I start vim with an ex-command as command line parameter, it won't show up in vim's command history. Why? Can I tell vim to do so?

Minimal example:

```sh
vim -c 'execute "help -c"'
```

Why I'm asking:

After grepping (with rg) in the command line, sometimes I want to open the results in vim. That's why I made a script that opens vim with the last ripgrep search as parameter, for example:

```sh
nvim -c 'execute "RgRaw failed --glob !lib"'
```

After closing the search (inside vim), I would like to simply repeat (and maybe adapt) this search via <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>.

- This specific workflow needs [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim), [vim-agriculture](https://github.com/jesseleite/vim-agriculture) to be installed.
- I use nvim here, because vim (8.2.2398) shows a warning (twice): "E994: Not allowed in a popup window"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I start vim with an ex-command as command line parameter, it won't show up in vim's command history. Why?

Presumably because [only commands that are typed](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/40be52ba71b9d6a7f586b1e77db8e827ff4c0c42/runtime/doc/cmdline.txt#L63-L64) interactively while Vim is running are remembered:

> - Only commands that are typed are remembered.  Ones that completely come from
>   mappings are not put in the history.

That's not the case of commands executed via the `-c` flag; those are not typed interactively; they're processed [before `VimEnter`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/40be52ba71b9d6a7f586b1e77db8e827ff4c0c42/runtime/doc/starting.txt#L940):

> The commands given with the |-c| and |+cmd| arguments are executed.

---

> Can I tell vim to do so?

Try this:

```
augroup CustomHistory | au!
    au VimEnter * eval v:argv
        \ ->copy()
        \ ->filter({i, v -> i > 0 && v:argv[i - 1] == '-c'})
        \ ->map({_, v -> histadd('cmd', v)})
augroup END
```

For more info, see:

- [:h v:argv](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v:argv)
- [:h copy()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#copy())
- [:h filter()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#filter())
- [:h map()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#map())
- [:h histadd()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#histadd())

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks a lot. I just noticed that "execute" will be added to the history, too. Then I noticed that I can drop it completely: `vim -c "RgRaw failed --glob !lib"`. Is there any reason why I should use "execute" for this use case?

Comment: This works fine in vim. But in neovim, I get this warning: `E492: Not an editor command: eval v:argv ->copy() ->filter({i, v -> i > 0 && v:argv[i - 1] == '-c'}) ->map({_, v -> histadd('cmd', v)})`. Any idea why?

Comment: *Is there any reason why I should use "execute" for this use case?*  I don't see any reason to use `:execute` here. *Any idea why?* Because this uses Vim 8.2 syntaxes, and Neovim is a fork of Vim 7.4.  I don't use Neovim anymore, but try this (untested): `call map(filter(copy(v:argv), {i, v -> i > 0 && v:argv[i - 1] == '-c'}), {_, v -> histadd('cmd', v)})`.

Comment: Well, this did not work: `E121: Undefined variable: v:argv`. Thanks anyway. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1231) for the other error (E994), I get only in vim.

Comment: That's because of [netrw which executes `:windo` on `VimEnter`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/8323cab31c3120a7f80cf3271a506a30ec04d99e/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim#L156).  `:windo` needs to temporarily focus other windows, but that's disallowed while a popup terminal is active.  You need to either: 1. remove netrw directory handler with `autocmd VimEnter * if exists("#FileExplorer") | exe "au! FileExplorer *" | endif`; or 2. disable netrw interface entirely with `let g:loaded_netrwPlugin = 1`; or 3. delay `:Rg` with a timer: `vim -c 'call timer_start(0, {-> execute("Rg")})'`.

Comment: FWIW, Vim provides `matchfuzzypos()` since [8.2.1726](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.1726) which lets you build your own fuzzy commands.  This might not be as powerful as `fzf(1)`, but it definitely gives you much more control than a compilation of third-party plugins.

Comment: Wow, you know a lot about vim!  *You need to either: ...* I guess option 1 and 2 don't play well with *vim-vinegar*. But option 3 works well! Thanks again. *Vim provides `matchfuzzypos()`* This sounds interesting (and like a lot of work)! But I'm fine with using *ripgrep* + *fzf*. I have these installed anyway.

Comment: After trying this in practice I noticed: When I run `vim -c "call timer_start(0, {-> execute('Rg')})"`, I get a fzf list but I can't open a match with "Enter" anymore!